Expectation values with finite number of shots with qsimcirq
I was using qsimcirq for VQE to obtain exact expectation values of the energy for a certain Hamiltonian with
qsim_simulator.simulate_expectation_values(qc,observables)

How can I do that with a finite number of shots?
There is a question about this but it is from 2020, maybe there is a buil-in solution now.
